# Aplicar css no parent

Tags: css, angularjs, css3

Tenho um input sem bordas dentro de uma div e ao lado do input tem uma lupa, nesse caso ele é um campo de pesquisa, até onde eu sei não é possível com css e sim somente com javascript, mais de repente alguém possa me dar uma idéia, preciso que quando clicar no input text a div fique com uma borda personalizada.

Abaixo vou anexar uma imagem de como é o componente, observe que o contorno é uma div cinza e dentro dela possui um input e um img, ao clicar no input essa div cinza deve ficar azul.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostre seu código e explique melhor o que quer fazer. Talvez seja possível sem aplicar css no parent (o que de fato o CSS não faz).

Comment: Veja na imagem acima, creio que dê pra entender bem o que preciso fazer, a ideia é tentar não usar javascript

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando angular criei uma diretiva que faz essa funcionalidade para meu campos e quanto for campos simples eu pego o próprio focus do input e seto a borda para ele, creio ser a solução mais limpa possível, para quem interessar segue o código:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function inputFocus() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($element) {
        $element.bind("focus", function(event) {
            jQuery($element).parent().addClass('div-focus-input');
        });

        $element.bind("focusout", function (event) {
            jQuery($element).parent().removeClass('div-focus-input');
        });
      }
    };
  }

  angular.module('myApp').directive('inputFocus', inputFocus);

})();
```

Comment: Sugiro inclusão da tag angular para que o artigo possa ser melhor aproveitado.